# xoauth_intuit_authid missing in request

Tags: php, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am getting the following error while calling the QBO API

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Fri, 21 Jun 2013 12:35:15 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix)
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth oauth_problem="parameter_absent", oauth_parameters_absent="xoauth_intuit_authid"
Content-Length: 75
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

oauth_problem=parameter_absent&oauth_parameters_absent=xoauth_intuit_authid
```

searched everywhere no post found related to the error

here is my request

```
"POST https:\/\/qbo.sbfinance.intuit.com\/resource\/payment\/v2\/718749385?oauth_consumer_key=qyprdhQBhe1RxpU8hMUpPjojNnJ7MQ&oauth_nonce=dGVzdDUxYzQ1MGM1YWNhNjU1MWM0NTBjNWFjYWIz&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1371820229&oauth_token=qyprd4C4wRVcFA94McMXPxYpEUpeYorIiVv4rkhZ5IoFu0ML&oauth_version=1.0&xoauth_intuit_authid=718749385 HTTP\/1.1\r\nContent-Type: application\/xml\r\nAuthorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"qyprdhQBhe1RxpU8hMUpPjojNnJ7MQ\"oauth_timestamp=\"1371820229\"oauth_nonce=\"dGVzdDUxYzQ1MGM1YWNhNjU1MWM0NTBjNWFjYWIz\"oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\"oauth_token=\"qyprd4C4wRVcFA94McMXPxYpEUpeYorIiVv4rkhZ5IoFu0ML\"oauth_version=\"1.0\"xoauth_intuit_authid=\"718749385\"oauth_signature=\"4Ozgam5ixNleV1cWNQti\/mAV5Zo=\"\r\nContent-Length: 334\r\n\r\n<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n<Payment xmlns=\"http:\/\/www.intuit.com\/sb\/cdm\/v2\" xmlns:ns2=\"http:\/\/www.intuit.com\/sb\/cdm\/qbopayroll\/v1\" xmlns:ns3=\"http:\/\/www.intuit.com\/sb\/cdm\/qbo\"><Header><CustomerId>1<\/CustomerId><TotalAmt>0.00<\/TotalAmt><\/Header><Line><Amount>0.00<\/Amount><TxnId>4<\/TxnId><\/Line><\/Payment>\n
```

I have tried with realmid as the value for the missing parameter

Comment: What are you using to sign the header? it doesnt look right. Also the parameters must be in the correct order per the oauth spec or it is rejected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the incorrect base path ... i got the problem solved by correcting the same.